# MySQL calculated variable in CASE statement

Tags: mysql

I am fairly new to this and wanted to see what I was doing wrong here. Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
      register_date, 
      day_total, 
      (num_qtrs * .25) 
        + (num_dimes * .10) 
        + (num_nickles * .05) 
        + (num_pennies *.01) AS coin_total,
      CASE WHEN day_total = coin_total 
         THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END 'Match'
   FROM 
      Register;
```

I kept getting this error message - Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'coin_total' in 'field list'

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL @variables, you can do it inline by declaring the variable via an alias select, then set the value to that computation but still save as the final column name.

```
SELECT 
      register_date, 
      day_total, 
      @myTotalCoins := (num_qtrs * .25) 
        + (num_dimes * .10) 
        + (num_nickles * .05) 
        + (num_pennies *.01) AS coin_total,
      CASE WHEN day_total = @myTotalCoins 
         THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END 'Match'
   FROM 
      Register,
      ( select @myTotalCoins := 0 ) sqlvars;
```

the second alias must be a select, but the "@variable" will get created of the respective date type, numeric, date, string.  Then, when you use them in the query as

```
@myTotalCoins := (computation)
```

It stores the computation to that variable at that moment for that row and can now be used for your comparison.  You can also use this technique for generating roll-up totals such as getting running totals per customer, per day, per whatever.  You can define as many variable you want in the select and they will all be available in similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real need for a variable here. They tend to make thinks more complicated, and they can be slow.

You can either repeat the expression:

```
SELECT 
    register_date, 
    day_total, 
    num_qtrs * .25 + num_dimes * .10 + num_nickles * .05 + num_pennies *.01 AS coin_total,
    CASE 
        WHEN day_total = num_qtrs * .25 + num_dimes * .10 + num_nickles * .05 + num_pennies *.01 
        THEN 'Yes' 
        ELSE 'NO' 
    END match
```

FROM Register;

Or you can wrap the query:

```
SELECT 
    t.*,
    CASE WHEN day_total = coin_total THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END match
FROM (
    SELECT 
        register_date, 
        day_total, 
        num_qtrs * .25 + num_dimes * .10 + num_nickles * .05 + num_pennies *.01 AS coin_total
   FROM Register
  ) t
```

Side notes:

- don't use the single quote to declare identifiers; single quotes should be used for string literals only; if your idenfier contains special characters (which is not the case here), you can use backticks instead
- there is no need for parentheses around the multiplications in the sum; MySQL knows about prescendence in arithmetic operations